# Mysql Error ONLY on production server, ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core, iis, entity-framework-core

I've deployed my asp.net core 5 web api on IIS on the production server, and i'm getting this error:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20004]
> An error occurred using the connection to database 'myDbName' on server 'my Ip (es. 171.1.1.0)'.
> fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[10100]
> An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'Orders_Sys_WebAPI.Models.serviziContext'.
> System.InvalidOperationException: An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure. Consider enabling transient error resiliency by adding 'EnableRetryOnFailure()' to the 'UseMySql' call.
> MySqlConnector.MySqlException (0x80004005): Connect Timeout expired.
> MySqlConnector.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.

I'm getting this error ONLY on the production server. I tried deploying on IIS on my laptop and everything works perfectly.

Is there any configuration on the server i'm missing? any ideas?

Comment: What is the connection string you used? Did your MySQL database administrators help check the network connection?

Comment: @LexLi the connection string is the same i used on my laptop:"server=ip;port=3306;user id=userName;database=dbName; password=pw", the network connection is fine

Comment: The connection string looks good, but too early to say network connection is fine. You need to use tools like Wireshark to verify packets to port 3306 of your database server and check further, as “Connect Timeout expired” is most likely caused by network issues.

Comment: Thank you @LexLi, it was a network connection problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out with infrastructure team it was a network connection porblem. The server had some limitations.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

> I tried deploying on IIS on my laptop and everything works perfectly

But your error is...

> Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.

Did you check that mysqld was running without interruptions? Is it on the same host as IIS? If not, was your laptop connected to the same network as the host where the errors were reported? Using the same switch? DNS configuration? Did you check the mysqld logs?